# What would be the ultimate golden standard for writing a login() function

Tags: javascript, authentication, testing, automation, testcafe

I was searching across the web for the ultimate 'login pattern' the one which includes a validation that login actually succeeds.
The problem - We do not allow using *expect* (aka assertions) within Pagemodels according to DRY and coding convention we decide on our team.
This is the current login method and it still flaky some times.
I want to ask you dear Automators, how you were designing the login including a validation?

```
/**
 * Actual login function
 */
async performLogin(): Promise<void> {
   console.log(`perform login`);
   await t
   .typeText(this.Email, username, {
      replace: true,
      paste: true
   })
   .typeText(this.Password, password, {
      replace: true,
      paste: true
   })
   .click(this.buttonSignIn)
}

/**
 * Login validation
 */
async login(): Promise<void> {
   await t.wait(7000)
   const getURL: any = ClientFunction(() => window.location.href)
   let currentURL: string = await getURL()

   while (currentURL === basePM.urlLogin) {
      this.performLogin()
      await t.eval(() => location.reload(true))
      currentURL = await getURL()
   }
}
```

Comment: You might get better answers in https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 5):

It's difficult to say anything precise without a working example.

`wait(7000)` looks a little redundant. If you want to be sure that you are on the correct page, you can check if an element exists by the selector. TestCafe has a built-in waiting mechanism, which allows you to avoid using the `wait` method: https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/built-in-waiting-mechanisms.html.

You missed the `await` keyword before the `this.performLogin()` call. The cause of flaky tests can be here.

The `while` statement looks redundant as well, since you can use smart assertion with client functions. However, it looks like some specifics of your site force you to reload the page. In a general case, you do not need to reload the page after the login.

Comment: Thanks, @Alex, the main purpose of the question was to get more ideas about get familiar with more robust and unwait depending waits such as retrieve the current page URL and assert it to the expect one. but how would you implement a validation which we are at the current page within a function if we not allow to use asserts within functions?

Comment: You can use assertions inside functions. As for your second question, there're two options. You can validate not only the current page URL, but also check whether the current page contains some element indicating a login state (for example, a profile link with a username). So, you can use either of the approaches.